# How to generate armeabi-v7a of libassimp.so.4.1.0 for Assimp

Tags: android

I am using Assimp source code to generate Android ARM binary. After CMake it provide me x86_64 libassimp.so every time.

I am using Assimp Source code 4.1.0 and compile it using following steps -

```
1. Set up android toolchain
export NDK_PATH=/path/to/your/android/ndk/
not go to android-ndk-r8c\build\tools
run the command:
sh make-standalone-toolchain.sh –platform=android-8 –ndk-dir=$NDK_PATH –install-dir=/Android/sdk/android-toolchain –toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3
which will build file scripts of the toolchain
now run the command
export ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN=$HOME/Android/sdk/android-toolchain
and also
export ANDTOOLCHAIN=$HOME/Android/android-cmake/toolchain/android.toolchain.cmake
to the path need to add :
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Android/sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Android/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Android/sdk/android-toolchain/bin

so lets begin, download the last source of assimp library from http://assimp.sourceforge.net and open terminal(cygwin or mac terminal) , go to assimp directory and type :
mkdir buildandroid
cd buildandroid
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$ANDTOOLCHAIN -DENABLE_BOOST_WORKAROUND=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/assimp-2.0 -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a _DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=android-8 -DANDROID_FORCE_ARM_BUILD=TRUE ..

this will create files and folders in the build directory, now go to the file link.txt inside : buildandroid => code => cMakeFiles => assimp.dir => link.txt
search for the string -soname, libassimp.so.3 and remove the .3 from the extension of the library (if not it will make problems in loading later from the android)
do the same thing with file name relink.txt

now go back to the root directory of buildandroid and run :
make
process of building will begin, the shared library will be in parent lib folder and wll consist from symbolic links and so library which will called libassimp.so.version_number. remove the version number makeing the file name only be libassimp.so
```

In the end, I am getting x86_64 libassimp.so instead armeabi-v7a. Please let me know if anybody now, how to generate armeabi-v7a libassimp.so. Any help will be appreciated.